# Using union on two lists is not working as expected

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0

I've read about thirty posts on this subject and *thought* I followed your instructions to the letter.

Here is the class I'm using:

```
public class UserID
{
    public int user_id { get; set; }
    public bool exists { get; set; }
}
```

I've created two good lists.

```
List<UserID> List1 = new List<UserID>();
List<UserID> List2 = new List<UserID>();
```

I've populated both lists successfully.

I'm trying to get a list of unique user ids.  I found the union method for lists and gave it a shot.

```
List<UserID> ResultList = new List<UserID>();

ResultList = List1.Union(List2).ToList();
```

Here's the issue.  After the last line here runs the ResultList is just the two lists put together.

List1 has { 10, 20, 30, 40 }
List2 has { 10, 30, 40, 50, 60 }

I'm expecting the union to give me:

ResultList = { 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60 }

but instead it's giving me:

ResultList = { 10, 20, 30, 40, 10, 30, 40, 50, 60 }

What am I doing wrong?  I've read a bunch of different posts that all say the same thing - basically the usage.  Am I not using it correctly?  I'm not getting any errors, it just isn't giving me the union I was expecting.

Comment: Union will add the 2 lists together without checking their values or removing duplicates. you can call Distinct() after the union, and it will give you the unique values without duplicates

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that compiler doesn't know how to compare two `UserID` objects.It uses default equality comparer which compares your object by references.So even though they have same `user_id` they treated as different because the references are different.

You need to tell the compiler to compare your objects based on `user_id` property by either overriding `Equals` and `GetHashCode` methods in your class or implementing an [`IEqualityComparer`].[1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

`Union` does remove duplicates (see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb341731%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)). This is what makes it different to `Concat`.

However to do so it needs to be enable to compare the items in the two sequences in the way you're expecting (in that two instances of `UserId` with the internal value set to 10 are equal).

To do so, either provide an equality comparer, or implement IEquatable on the `UserId` class. The MSDN article has an example of doing this on a `Product` class.

Answer (score 0):

As Selman22 suggested I needed to use the [IEqualityComparer].

I added this to my code.

```
public class CompareUserIDs : IEqualityComparer<UserID>
{
    public bool Equals(UserID x, UserID y)
    {
        return x.user_id.Equals(y.user_id);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(UserID obj)
    {
        return obj.user_id.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

I then called it as follows:

```
IntermediateResult = List1.Union(List2).ToList();
IEqualityComparer<UserID> customComparer = new CompareResultTables();
IEnumerable<UserID> myresult = IntermediateResult.Distinct(customComparer);
```

And voila!  I had my, "union".  myresult contained only the unique elements from both lists.

Comment: Your comparer doesn't handle `null` `UserID` objects, and it almost certainly should.